# Image Hashing is not happening on static image when serving from AWS S3 in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cdn, nextjs-image

I want to serve all static resources like fonts and images from the CDN server. So currently static images and fonts lie under `/public/images` and `/public/fonts`. On build, Next.js will hash every image and font under `.next/static/media`. As shown in the image below.

[image]

Now as per the [Asset Prefix](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix) document, I have also added a CDN path in the next.config.js

```
const getCDN = () => {
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV === 'staging') {
    return 'https://cdn.staging.mydomain.com.au/';
  }

   if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV === 'production') {
    return 'https://cdn.mydomain.com/';
  }
};

module.exports = {
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: getCDN(),
}
```

Also, I have copied all `.next/static` folder content and uploaded it to S3 under `mydomain/_next/static`. S3 Path looks like below

```
s3://mydomain/_next/static/logo.68a3dfc9.png
```

Now the logo image code looks like

```
 <Image
      layout="fixed"
      width={90}
      height={34}
      src={'images/logo.png'}
      alt="realestateview.com.au logo"
      />
```

But after building it nothing had changed

```
<img alt="mydomain.com logo" src="/images/logo.png" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%">
```

Am I missing something ? What do I need to do to serve that logo image from CDN and that hash? The desired image tag should be as shown below.

```
<img alt="mydomain.com logo" src="https://cdn.mydomain.com/_next/static/media/logo.68a3dfc9.png" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%">
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab to verify which origin is being used for fetching the images?

Comment: Yes I checked it showing mydomain.com/_next/static/*** - not using cdn path.